# Implementing unsafe Java interfaces

Tags: inheritance, scala, language-interoperability

I've ran into a problem recently while developing with Spring Security. It has an interface `GrantedAuthority` with following signature:

```
public interface GrantedAuthority extends Serializable, Comparable
```

And as for Java 1.5 and later, the interface `Comparable` takes a type parameter `T`, which is omitted in Spring Security libraries (obviously, for JVM 1.4 compatibility).

So I am trying to implement `GrantedAuthority` in Scala.

```
class Role extends GrantedAuthority {
  . . .
  def compareTo(obj: Any): Int = obj match {
    case (r: Role) => r.toString.compareTo(this.toString)
    case _ => -1
  }
}
```

It does not compile:

```
error: class Role needs to be abstract, since method compareTo in trait Comparable of type (T)Int is not defined
```

How can I implement such interface in Scala?

Comment: Sounds related to raw types like this: https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/ticket/2970#comment:3

Comment: Thanks, retronym. So the final answer is, actually, "wontfix"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interop problems with Java Generics come in (at least) two forms:

1. Java code that omits type arguments, as in your example, leads to 'raw types'. `Comparable` is treated as the existential type `Comparable[_]`. Sometimes you can cast your way out of this problem. However, I don't see a way to implement `def compareTo(other: _) = ...` in this case.
2. Java generics don't have a notion of declaration site variance. To extend `Comparable[T]` with a contravariant scala trait `Ordering[-T]` an error would occur unless you use the `@uncheckedVariance` annotation. ([Discussion on the mailing list](http://old.nabble.com/Contravariant-Ordering-T-,-java.util.Comparator,-and--uncheckedVariance-td25979631.html))

I suggest you try to upgrade to Spring 3.x which is compiled against Java 1.5. If this is not possible, write a base class `BaseGrantedAuthority` in Java that implements `compareTo` and delegates to a template method that can implemented in Scala.

Comment: I was interested in this interop problem, rather than solving my particular case -- you showed me the point perfectly. Thanks!